# How to fix a Voter Must implement VoterInterface error

Tags: symfony

Symfony is not recognizing my Voter class. it is suggesting me to implement VoterInterface which I have already implemented.

I have both implemented the VoterInterface and  extended the Voter class

```
services.yml
parameters:
    admin_mail: manager@example.com
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false
        bind:
            $adminMail: 'manager@example.com'
            $requestLogger: '@monolog.logger.request'
            Psr\Log\LoggerInterface: '@monolog.logger.request'

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    app.form_login_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
        arguments: ["@router", "@security.password_encoder"]

    app.post_entity:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\Post
        arguments: ['@security.helper']

    app.post_voter:
        class: AppBundle\Security\PostVoter
        arguments: ['@security.access.decision_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }


security.yml

security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:
                        password: ryanpass
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    admin:
                        password: kitten
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
        database_users:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                username_parameter: _username
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
                invalidate_session: true
            provider: database_users
            logout_on_user_change: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
        allow_if_all_abstain: false


PostVoter.php

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security;

use AppBundle\Entity\Post;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class PostVoter extends Voter implements VoterInterface
{
    const VIEW = 'view';
    const EDIT = 'edit';
    const DELETE = 'delete';

    private $decisionManager;

    public function __construct(AccessDecisionManagerInterface $decisionManager)
    {
        $this->decisionManager = $decisionManager;
    }

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        if (!in_array($attribute, [self::VIEW, self::EDIT, self::DELETE])) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!$subject instanceof Post) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        $post = $subject;

        switch($attribute) {
            case self::VIEW:
                return $this->canView($post, $user);
            case self::EDIT:
                return $this->canEdit($post, $user);
            case self::DELETE:
                return $this->canDelete($post, $user);
        }

        throw new \LogicException('This code should not be reached!');
    }

    private function canView(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        if ($this->canEdit($post, $user)) {
            return true;
        }

        return !$post->isPrivate();
    }

    private function canEdit(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        return $user->isEqualTo($post->getUser());
    }

    private function canDelete(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        return canEdit($user, $post);
    }

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $subject, $attributes)
    {

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if (!$this->supports($attribute, $subject) && $this->voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject)) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
            }
        }
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;

    }

}


PostController.php

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use AppBundle\Entity\Post;
use AppBundle\Entity\Comment;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Form\PostType;
use AppBundle\Updates\SiteUpdateManager;
use AppBundle\Form\CommentType;


class PostController extends Controller
{   


    public function indexAction(SiteUpdateManager $siteUpdateManager)
    {   
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Post');

        $posts = $repository->findAllPostWithCommentOrderedByIdDesc();

        $post = new Post();

        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);


        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'form' => $form->createView()
            ]);


    }

    public function showAction(Post $post)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('view', $post);
    }

    public function updateAction()
    {

    }

    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();

        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {   

            $image = $post->getImage();
            $imageName = $this->generateUniqueFileName(). '.' . $image->guessExtension();
            try {
                $image->move(
                    $this->getParameter('post_image_directory'),
                    $imageName
                );
            } catch (FileException $e) {
                return new Response('File upload error: '.$e->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            $post->setUser($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser());
            $post->setImage($imageName);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('post_list');
        }

        return $this->render('post/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);    
    }

    public function deleteAction(Post $post)
    {   
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('delete', $post);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($post);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('post_list');

    }

    public function generateUniqueFileName()
    {
        return sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    }

}             

Post.php

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Comment;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class Post
{
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $description;
    private $image;
    private $comments;
    private $user;

    private $security;



    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comments[] = $comment;
    }

    public function isPrivate()
    {   
        return in_array("ROLE_USER", $this->security->getUser()->getRoles());
        return $this->getUser()->isEqualTo($this->security->getUser());
    }

}

User.php

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\Post;
use AppBundle\Entity\Comment;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $username;
    private $roles;
    private $plainPassword;
    private $password;
    private $posts;
    private $comments;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comments[] = $comment;
    }

    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    public function addPost(Post $post)
    {
        $this->posts[] = $post;
    }


    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user) {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->getUsername() !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->getPassword() !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

AppBundle\Security\PostVoter should implement the Symfony\Component\Securi
  ty\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface interface when used as voter.

Comment: From the docs "A custom voter needs to implement `VoterInterface` **OR** extend `Voter`, which makes creating a voter even easier", so why your concrete `PostVoter` class use both implementations?

Comment: I also tried with Voter and VoterInterface alone. It is spitting the same error.

Comment: So please add the full stack trace of the error, the symfony version used and reduce the code to the minimum needed for debugging (if you can, not in the same window). PS: and remember to clear the cache after each modification :)

Comment: Only use Voter alone.  In fact you would be better off just deleting your current class and then start over with the example in the docs.  But first, get yourself an IDE that will check your code.  You have all kinds of problems with method signatures and namespacing.

Comment: I solved the error. I accidently put my Voter class in the tests directory. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: I had the same error, and it was also because I had forgotten a folder on the service definition... But the error should be something like "Voter not found" instead of a missing implementation :/